# Acelerar seleção por varchar - MariaDB 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Eu tenho uma tabela InnoDB com 105 colunas e cerca de 300.000 linhas. Nela existe um varchar(24) onde é guardado o nome de usuário.

Quando executo queries como essas:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY username='algumUsuario';
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='algumUsuario';
```

O tempo é de 1 segundo ou mais, para selecionar apenas um usuário na tabela.

O que pode ser feito para acelerar essa seleção? Pesquisando, vi algumas coisas sobre indexes, porém não funcionou para este caso, apenas para colunas numéricas (int).

Fiz testes aumentando o `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, mas também não ajudou.